# Matcher.matches() is always false

Tags: java, regex

I tried to do a Kata code and it should be easy, but I don't know why it doesn't work. The goal of this exercise is to convert a string to a new string where each character in the new string is `"("` if that character appears only once in the original string, or `")"` if that character appears more than once in the original string. Ignore capitalization when determining if a character is a duplicate.

My code to test was:

```
public class Kata {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t = "recede";
        System.out.println(Kata.encode(t));
    }

    public static String encode(String word){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
        for (char c : arr) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[" + c  
                    + String.valueOf(c).toUpperCase() 
                    + "]{2,}+$");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
            if (matcher.matches()) 
                result.append(")");
            else 
                result.append("(");
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

I tried to change `matches()` for `find()`, and always write `"(((((("`, and in debug always match false in the if condition.

In addition I want to say I tried other patterns with same result like `"[" + c + String.valueOf(c).toUpperCase() + "]{2,}"` and I know other ways to make the Kata but I want to know why pattern and matcher fails because it’s not the first time it happens in Java and in other languages I didn't have problems like this.

Comment: Why are you doing `toUpperCase()`? Also, do you know what `^` and `$` mean? Each of these on their own will result in your pattern failing to match.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel They try to perform a case insensitive search. But the pattern only matches a string with two or more `c` characters, so the code does not work. Basically, it is a "how to count occurrences of a specific character in a string in a case insensitive way" to me.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew But they aren't asking for a case-insensitive match with their code.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel `recede` is the input, all letters are lower case. So, `[rR]` will match `r` or `R`. The quick answer is `Pattern.compile("(?i)" + c + "[^"  + c + "]*"  + c` or - with special character support - `Pattern.compile("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(c) + "[^"  + Pattern.quote(c) + "]*"  + Pattern.quote(c))` with `matcher.find()`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I guess I'm blind... I missed that `+ c` on the previous line.

Comment: What is the desired output of this program, and what is the URL to the code challenge? You need to provide this info.

Comment: With regex: https://ideone.com/tURdoU. Without regex: https://ideone.com/8iRc3F

Answer (score 2):

Why your solution does not work:

- You are building a wrong pattern. `^[cC]{2,}+$` only matches a string with two or more `c` or `C` characters. To match a string that contains two `c` or `C` letters you need a pattern like `(?i)c.*c`, `(?i)c.*?c` or better `(?i)c[^c]*c`.
- The `.matches()` method requires a full string match, so the anchors in your pattern are redundant. The regex like `(?i)c[^c]*c` requires the use of `Matcher.find()` to look for a match anywhere inside the string.

So, you can use

```java
for (char c : arr) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)" + c + "[^"  + c + "]*"  + c);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
    if (matcher.find()) 
        result.append(")");
    else 
        result.append("(");
}
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/tURdoU). If you need to support special characters, you could use `Pattern.compile("(?i)" + Pattern.quote(c) + "[^" + Pattern.quote(c) + "]*"  + Pattern.quote(c))`.

Or, without a regex:

```java
for (char c : arr) {
    if (word.toUpperCase().chars().filter(ch -> ch == Character.toUpperCase(c)).count() > 1) 
        result.append(")");
    else 
        result.append("(");
}
```

See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/8iRc3F).

Comment: thanks a lot , now it works with regex , and i really like the alternative solution !

Answer (score 2):

No need for a regular expression here, just populate a frequency map. You should pre-compute the duplicates.

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Kata {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String t = "recede";
        System.out.println(encode(t)); // "()()()"
    }

    public static String encode(String word) {
        Map<Character, Integer> frequency = new HashMap<>();
        for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
            frequency.merge(Character.toLowerCase(ch), 1, Integer::sum);
        }
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(word.length());
        for (char ch : word.toCharArray()) {
            result.append(frequency.get(Character.toLowerCase(ch)) > 1 ? ')' : '(');
        }
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finnally after Wiktor Stribizew comment ican understand more my confussion with regex, and find a better or more clean to read expresion for this. the final code is:

```
 public static String encode(String word){
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            char[] arr = word.toCharArray();
        for (char c : arr) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)" + "(.*" + c + ".*){2,}");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
            result.append(matcher.find() ? ")" : "(");
        }

            return result.toString();
    }
```